# Is there a sample ArcGIS Server service for US zip codes?

Tags: arcgis-server, data

Esri provide a [sample ArcGIS Server](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer) instance which contains states, block groups, etc.

Is there a similar publicly-accessible ArcGIS Server instance anywhere which contains US zip codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using google, [searching for strings](https://www.google.com/search?q=mapserver%20zip%20code%20%22Service%20Description:%22) that appear on the service description page,  I found [this layer in the national map](http://services.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/govunits/MapServer/19).

**Edit:** the National Map "govunits" service has been moved [here](https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/govunits/MapServer), but ZIP codes are no longer included in it.

Comment: How do I use this REST service in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I can only find paid for data sources, as I assumed you wanted the data. In short, I dont think you can access this data, without first purchasing it.

Sorry it can't be a better answer.  As an aside, there's movement in teh UK to make this kind of data free, as we, as tax payers, have paid for its development.  I for one am not holding my breath...

Answer (score 1):

There are many [Zip code databases on ArcGIS Hub](https://hub.arcgis.com/search?q=zip%20code), mostly for specific counties.

Answer (score 0):

If [ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs)](http://www.census.gov/geo/ZCTA/zcta.html) are good enough for your needs, the Census Bureau provides the 2000 and 2010 versions on their [TIGER/Line download site](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main). The Census Bureau sums up their reason for not having official ZIP Code boundaries nicely:

> The Census Bureau does not have maps or digital files showing the boundaries of U.S. Postal Service ZIP Codes. The fact that ZIP Codes aren't required to be polygons makes them difficult to map. They are networks of streets served by mail carriers or just individual post offices and are a tool for mail delivery. They also change periodically as required to meet Post Office operational needs. Various companies have created maps by interpolating boundaries between occurrences of ZIP Codes on the ground. However, this does not guarantee that the U.S. Postal Service delivery routes will follow this interpretation. [[Source]](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tigermap.html#ZIP)